# HTTP / Twilio requests via PHP in Google App Engine being repeated

Tags: php, google-app-engine, twilio

I am trying to migrate a PHP application that uses Twilio to Google Apps and have run into a bit of a snag. As a simple test, I sent a single text message to my cell phone from within the Google App that I created. It sends fine but I receive the message twice; to confirm it was actually executing twice I sent the epoch time - they're about 1 second apart.

I checked the logs and saw this - "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application." I tried removing the Twilio usage entirely and replaced it with a simple "Hello World" echo, same message appeared in the log for that request.

How can I avoid this sort of behavior?

**UPDATE**

Here are the headers from my Requestb.in test using the following code. The bin was hit twice from the same IP address - I only went to the App's page one time.

```
<?php
$result = file_get_contents('http://requestb.in/BINID');
echo $result;
```

Headers -

**First Request:**
User-Agent: AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: s~MYAPP)
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Request-Id: e7583bda-dfeb-4431-92a5-aa4af0bf06e8
Host: requestb.in

**Second request:**
User-Agent: AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: s~MYAPP)
X-Request-Id: e766375b-bea8-4b79-a869-e2603309bec7
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: requestb.in
Connection: close

**SECOND UPDATE**

I added the epoch time as a GET variable to the requestb.in address, the bin was hit twice with the exact same epoch, two different IP addresses, one second apart. So this tells me that the code was executed one time but somehow accessed the bin twice from two IP addresses. Sometimes it seems to only be one IP address. Really puzzled here.. I even tried from scratch with a new app, same result.

Comment: It just randomly seems to have stopped doing the repetition.. after hours of trying to figure it out.

Comment: Or maybe not. Seems to stop the repetition randomly and then it returns

Comment: Last comment/updated - I am now running Laravel on the App Engine and this problem has not reappeared.. so far. If anyone has any clue what may have caused this, feedback would be helpful. The application will be sending out text messages, obviously duplicates are a problem.

Comment: Do you have page speed enabled ?

Comment: Do you have page speed enabled ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Honestly, I decided to move on to Amazon EC2 instead, set it up all effortlessly. I may return to GAE in the future but not for PHP..

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find this message ""This request caused a new process to be started for your application, " is unrelated.

Unless you use warmup requests, you will always see this message if an instance is started to serve user facing request.

I would look at your code and see how the message sending code could be executed twice.
Try doing some logging around the sending code and see if you get that log message in the same request twice.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to log? I tried `file_put_contents` but it returned an error that it was write only. I tried a `file_get_contents` with Request Bin and it appears that two IP addresses requested the content - is it possible that I somehow launched two instances of this application?

Comment: Confirmed - tried a request again and they were one second apart, same IP address except for the last digit - .48 and .49

Comment: Unfortunately I know absolutely nothing about PHP so am not sure how you do logging.  I think there is a syslog call I PHP that will let you log.

Comment: It almost seems like everything is being executed twice from two different IP addresses. I'm new to Google Apps.. I don't know if this is a setting somewhere that I am unaware of, some sort of recursion maybe?

Comment: to write logs use syslog -> syslog(LOG_DEBUG, 'blah blah blah); which will write to you applications logs.